# Resolving Conflict with Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 in VB.NET .NET 7.0 Project

Tags: .net, vb.net

Context
I am working on a VB.NET web application targeting .NET 7.0, where I need to perform CRUD operations on Gmail using the Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 package. However, I've encountered an unresolved conflict with this package.

Issue

When I try to execute my class with  Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 via NuGet, I get InnerException = {"Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Gmail.v1, Version=1.64.0.3231, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Google.Apis.Gmail.v1, Version=1.64.0.3231, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e...

Question

Are there known compatibility issues with Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 and VB.NET projects targeting .NET 7.0?
What steps can I take to resolve this conflict and successfully integrate the Gmail API into my project?
Are there alternative approaches or packages I could consider for implementing Gmail CRUD operations in a .NET 7.0 environment?
Additional Information

.NET version: .NET 7.0
IDE: [Visual Studio 2022]
Project type to integrate code: vb class
Project Configuration: Back end Server application in vb.Net to receive request over WebSocket and execute running on apache server or window server
What I've Tried

Firstable i made a console project for bulding my code with the same framework .NET 7.0 and is working well before integrate the code in the release in the vb.net .Net7.0 server application(class Project). I have attempted to find the conflit by removing assembly one by one.I Remark in my testing application is generated the dll see figure below ,on the side of class Project only Google.Protobuf.dll was generated whos is not in the console project.
i found a potential conflit with MySql.Data.dll and i updated the nuget,removed the nugget, delete debug folder and try again but only the Google.Protobuf.dll was generated.
dll generated from console project debug folder

[image: dll generated from console project debug folder]

Class projet debug folder

[image: Class projet debug folder]

Snippet code where error is generated

[image: class project snippet]

Conclusion
I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue or alternative methods for integrating Gmail functionality into a VB.NET .NET 7.0 application.

Comment: I assume you just upgraded it from previous .NET version? Did you do a "hard-clean": close VS, delete `bin` and `obj` folders and restart your PC?

Comment: i started from stratch with .Net 7.0 console, also delete bin and obj folder , delete gmail related nuget ,copied dll form debug console and paste in the project class still not found ,my visual code  and my window11 is up to date.